# Stepwise left_join/merge

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a main df of 250k observations to which I want to add a set of variables, which I had to compute in smaller dfs (5 different dfs of 50k observations each) due to the limitations in the left_join/merge-function's row size (of 2^31-1 observations).

I am now trying to use the left_join or merge-functions on the main df and the 5 smaller ones to add the columns for the new variables to the main df for 50k observations in each step.

```
mainFrame <- left_join(mainFrame, newVariablesFirstSubsample)
mainFrame <- left_join(mainFrame, newVariablesSecondSubsample)
mainFrame <- left_join(mainFrame, newVariablesThirdSubsample)
mainFrame <- left_join(mainFrame, newVariablesFourthSubsample)
mainFrame <- left_join(mainFrame, newVariablesFifthSubsample)
```

After the first left_join (which includes the new variables' values for the first 50k observations), R doesn't seem to include any values for the following groups of 50k observations, when I run the second to fifth left_joins. I derive this conclusion from building the summary stats for the respective columns after each left_join.

Any idea on what I do wrong or which other functions I might use?

Comment: Hi, have you tried using `data.table`? I did not remember having the limit of 2^31-1 observation

Comment: I have not - how would it work using data.table?

Comment: Same sintax that `merge`: `merge(dt1, dt2, by.x=c("X","Y"), by.x=c("Z","K"), all.x=T, all,y=F)` for a left join. You can make your dataframes datatables first: `mainFrame  <- as.data.table(mainFrame) `

Comment: It just gives me the error: 

Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'any'

Comment: If the number of rows are increasing after each join, that means whatever columns you are joining on are not unique --- this is probably bad.

Answer (score 0):

Data tables allow you to create "keys" which are R's version of SQL's indexes. That will help you to expedite the search for the columns that R uses for their merging or left-joining.

If I were you, I would just export all of them to csv files and work them out from SQL or using SSIS service.

The problem I'm noting is that you are realizing the error from the summary statistics. Have you tried reversing the order in which you insert the tables. Or explicitly stating the names of the columns used in your left join?

Please let me us know the outcome.

Comment: I followed your suggestion of reverting the order in which I insert the tables and the outcome really confuses me even more: I left_joined the last subsample first and what it does is to give me the same error that it gives me when I join the entire sample: Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
  std::bad_alloc. That means, that the error doesn't stem from the sample being too large, and I'm back to "start".

Comment: Try looking into the names of the columns in both data frames (do they match?). I'm not big on using left_join in R, try using merge and assigning the corresponding values to by.x = nameColumnLeftTable, and by.y = nameColumnRightTable

Comment: They have the exact same names, lengths and class. When I use merge, it gives me the following error: Error in merge.data.frame( ) : negative length vectors are not allowed.